# Chrome bug? CSS3 columns make an extra space on every new column

Tags: google-chrome, css, cross-browser

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/WCP5f/2/

If you open it with Chrome, you will see that every new column (not the first one) has an extra space over **only** the content of **the first** huge letter of each column.

Meanwhile, Firefox seems to be doing this right.

Is this a chrome bug? or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS multi-column layout of list items doesn't align properly in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314726/css-multi-column-layout-of-list-items-doesnt-align-properly-in-chrome)

Comment: I didnt really find any working solution in that thread

Comment: This also happens on mobile safari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WCP5f/3/

I switched the `.huge-letter` `font-size` to an EM instead of a PX value, and this seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Try removing the `line-height`.

Comment: Or, you can make the `line-height` an EM as well, and that fixes it.

Comment: Yes! I see. Adjusting the line-height, I can make it match. Thanks!